# Laravel 5.7 - Controle de barra lateral via Controller

Tags: html5, laravel-5

Estou desenvolvendo um site que contem uma barra lateral que irá mostrar algumas informações aos usuários. Essas informações estão em um banco de dados, logo tenho que acessa-las via `controller` para depois mandar para a `view`. Acontece que essa barra lateral é mostrada em todas as rotas do site

Qual a melhor maneira de resolver isso, sem ter que ficar repetindo o mesmo código, ou chamando um método várias vezes em todos os `controllers` do site?

**Template principal**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
@include('layouts/header')    
<div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 80px; margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @include('layouts/lateral') <!--Barra lateral comum a todos -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            @yield('content')   
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

@include('layouts/footer')

@yield('script')
```

**Barra lateral:**

```
<div class='card'>
    <div class="card-header">
        Informações Gerais
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <strong>Contas cadastradas: </strong> 1<br> <!-- Vem do banco -->
        <strong>Player online: </strong> 0 <br> <!-- Vem do banco -->
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pq não coloca no *Template principal*?

Comment: Vai dar no mesmo. De qualquer maneira, vou ter que ficar repetindo o mesmo código em todos os métodos de todos os controllers que retornam uma view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A técnica criada para fazer isso é com ViewComposers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers) que são dados que podem ser compartilhadas em diversas [Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views) do seu sistema de apenas um lugar. O [ViewComposers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers) é uma forma de criar apenas um retorno de dados e enviar essa informação para todas as [Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views) que podem ser configuradas para algumas, diversas ou todas as suas [Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views).

<sup>***Tradução Google***</sup>
[Os compositores de exibição são retornos de chamada ou métodos de classe que são chamados quando uma exibição é renderizada. Se você tiver dados que deseja vincular a uma visualização sempre que essa visualização for renderizada, um compositor de visualização organiza essa lógica em um único local.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers)

***Exemplo:***

Crie uma pasta dentro de `app\Http` com o nome de `ViewComposers`, e crie um classe dentro com o nome sugerido `SideBarComposer` com o seguinte código:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class SideBarComposer
{    

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $contas_cadastradas = 1;
        $jogadores_online = 1;
        $view->with('contas_cadastradas', $contas_cadastradas);
        $view->with('jogadores_online', $jogadores_online);
    }
}
```

onde os valores 1 em cada variável seria o retorno de sua base de dados por exemplo, pode injetar pelo construtor os `models` sem problemas ou usar a técnica qualquer de recuperação de informação.

Abra `AppServiceProvider` que está localizado na pasta `app\Providers` e dentro do método `boot` adicione a seguinte linha:

```
public function boot()
{
    ViewComposer::composer('*', \App\Providers\SideBarComposer::class);
}
```

<sup>**Observação:** não se esqueça de adicionar o `namespace` `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;` para ter acesso o método `ViewComposer::composer`.</sup>

isso configura o serviço criado ser carregado, e na configurações foi colocado um `*` que significa que esse `SideBarComposer` vai subir todas as vezes as informações que são compartilhadas em todas as páginas.

<sub>**Nota:** *Nada impende que essas informações suba para determinadas páginas é só colocar um `array` com os nomes da suas `Views`, mas, pelo que eu li na pergunta são para todas as páginas.*</sub>

Finalizando agora é só configurar na sua `view` o seguinte código:

```
<div class='card'>
    <div class="card-header">
        Informações Gerais
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <strong>Contas cadastradas: </strong> {{$contas_cadastradas}}<br>
        <strong>Player online: </strong> {{$jogadores_online}} <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

[O exemplo completo está no site do Framework Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers), siga a versão correspondente, do seu `Laravel`.